# Laravel - Number with 4 decimals

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to store 1 number with 4 decimals, in my database.

If i use **float** i can add only 2 decimals

```
$table->float('sell');
```

[image]

---

If I try with **decimal** i get an error

```
$table->decimal('sell', 1, 4);
```

The first number must be greater than or equal to the second number.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1427 For float(M,D), double(M,D) or decimal(M,D), M must be >= D (column '
```

sell'). (SQL: create table `customers` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `sell` decimal(1, 4) not null,
   `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)

**Any help?**

**Thanks**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the following;

```
$table->decimal('foo', 5, 4);
```

The first parameter is the total number of numbers, the second parameter is the "decimal precision".

Comment: No problem, confm :-)

Answer (score 22):

In your schema file.

```
 $table->decimal('your_field_name', 13, 4);
```

- **your_field_name** = Database field name.
- **13** = Total number of digit. **Example**- **$99,999,999,999.99**
- **4** = value after decimal. **Example** - $999,999,999.**9999**

Comment: works on laravel 8. perfect

Answer (score 3):

You have made a small mistake with parameter

```
$table->decimal('amount', 5, 2);
```

In above example first parameter is the field name. 
Second, parameter is the total length.
Third, parameter is the float value.

Answer (score 1):

Try number_format

**For laravel:**

```
{!! number_format((float)($item->amount), 5) !!}
```

**For Raw PHP:**

```
number_format((float)($yourVariable), 5)
```

Answer (score -2):

Please following code

`$table->float('sell', 5, 4);`
FLOAT equivalent for the database, 5 digits in total and 4 after the decimal point.

Thanks